# Get a list of email addresses from multiple e-mail messages in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, distribution-list

I have around 80 e-mails from different people in a separate inbox subfolder in Outlook. Is it possible to select them and extract all their mail addresses (into a distribution list/csv/clipboard, anything)?

I am using Outlook 2007. Also, any way which doesn't involve manually clicking on each mail would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming all the emails are in a single folder by themselves.
In Outlook:

1. From File Menu, pick "Import and Export"
2. Choose "export"
3. Choose "Comma seperated Values"
4. Specify the subfolder of the emails
5. Set the export filename
6. Important step: Click the Map Custom Fields" button. Clear all fields on the right, and then drag only the "From Addresses" from the left to right box.
7. Finish. This csv file will open in Excel, where you can manipulate, sort etc the list or copy/paste it to any other format.